# get filtered embeded elements from all class on mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, aggregation-framework

I got two class on Mongoengine:

```
class UserPoints(EmbeddedDocument):
   user = ReferenceField(User, verbose_name='user')
   points = IntField(verbose_name='points', required=True)
   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.points
```

And

```
 class Local(Document):
    token = StringField(max_length=250,verbose_name='token_identifier',unique=True)
    points = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(UserPoints),required=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

If i do something like: "LP = Local.objects.filter(points__user=user)" I got all the locals with userpoints from my user. But i Want all the UserPoints from a User. How can i?

I try also: "lUs = UserPoints.objects.filter(user=user)" but i got an empty Array.

PD: I do something like this to solve the problem, but it's not efficient.

```
 LDPoints = []
 LP = Local.objects.filter(points__user=user)
    print 'List P: '+str(len(LP))
    for local in LP:
            for points in local.points:
                    if points.user == user:
                            dPoints = parsePoints(points)
                            lDPoints.append(dPoints)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the original and getting venerable answer is that the aggregation framework has [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) now for some time, which is a lot cleaner that the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) method used in the original answer.

```
Local._get_collection().aggregate([
  { "$match": { "points.user": user } },
  { "$project": {
    "token": 1,
    "points": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$points",
        "as": "el",
        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.user", user ] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

The same principles apply though for obtaining "multiple" matches from an array in the collection you use the `aggregate()` method of the underlying driver, as called from `_get_collection()`.

---

## Original

The answer to avoid "filtering" your embedded documents for the selected "user" only is to use the [aggregation framework](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate). This allows you to manipulate the "array content" on the database server rather than filtering the results in your client code.

Aggregation is done with the raw pymongo driver methods, but since Mongoengine is built on top of this driver you access the raw collection object from your class with the `._get_collection()` method:

```
Local._get_collection().aggregate([
    # Match the documents that have the required user
    { "$match": {
         "points.user": user
    }},
    
    # unwind the embedded array to de-normalize
    { "$unwind": "$points" },

    # Matching now filters the elements
    { "$match": {
         "points.user": user
    }},

    # Group back as an array
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "token": { "$first": "$token" },
        "points": { "$push": "$points" }
    }}
 ])
```

If you have MongoDB 2.6 or greater on your server and your "user/points" combination is always unique you can alternately filter without the `$unwind|$match|$group` cycle using the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operators available there:

```
Local._get_collection().aggregate([
    # Match the documents that have the required user
    { "$match": {
         "points.user": user
    }},

    # Filter the array in place
    { "$project": {
        "token": 1,
        "points": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { 
                    "$map": {
                       "input": "$points",
                       "as": "el",
                       "in": {
                           "$cond": [
                               { "$eq": [ "$$el.user", user ] },
                               "$$el",
                               false
                           ]
                       }
                    }
                },
                [false]
            ]
        }
     }}
])
```

In the second case there the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) is a ternary operator which takes a logical expression as it's first argument and the values to return when that expression is either `true` or `false` as it's other arguments. Inside the `$map`, each element is tested to see if the condition is true, in this case "is the user field equal to the selected user".

Either the content of that array position is returned or otherwise `false`. The `$setDifference` takes the resulting array and "filters" the false values out, so only the matching elements are returned.

In the legacy approach, the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) pipeline operator is used to effectively turn each array element into it's own document with all other parent properties. This allows you to apply the same [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) condition, which unlike the initial query actually removes the documents which now as single elements no longer match your condition. You always want the first stage as there is no point processing this `$unwind|$match` combination on all of the documents that might not contain your matching condition.

The [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage brings everything back into line per document. Using the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) option to return all other fields that were essentially duplicated by the `$unwind` and the [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) operator to rebuild the array with the matching elements.

So while there no "built-in" methods to MongoEngine to do this sort of query, you can do this the MongoDB way by accessing the raw driver.

Also note that if you only expected **one** element to match in any array for your given "user" or other query, then you could alternately use the field projection form available to the raw driver as well. But the aggregation method is required for any more than one matching element of the array.